# How to add more than 2 detailTextLabel in TableView (Swift)

Tags: uiview, swift

I tried to add many details (fields) to display in TableView. by concat each fields and put in for detailTextLabel e.g.:

From:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"test")

    cell.textLabel.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc

    return cell
}
```

To

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Test")
    cell.textLabel?.text=tasksList[indexPath.row].name
    var yString = tasksList[indexPath.row].desc
    var xString = tasksList[indexPath.row].amnt

    var zString = xString+" "+yString
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text=zString
    return cell
}
```

Could anyone point out any other ways for better code for many fields to display in the view.

Comment: You can use custom cell for it.

Comment: I searched "custom cell" found relevant code and tutor. Thks

Answer (score 0):

I think your first method is great.  In storyboard inside a prototype cell you can place several UILabels.  Then just update each label as you did.  You can place labels in a xib or create them in code.  But there is nothing wrong with having several labels and then updating them individually.  This gives more flexibility that concatenation because you can justify the text in each label as required to make the tableview pretty.  So each cell row has good alignment with the one above it.

Comment: I came from PHP and ofcourse new in Swift/Xcode. Doing each one like that have difficulty when reteived data from database to array. I can not assign to the array  <br/>[cell.textLabel?.text=tasksList[indexPath.row].name
        var yString = tasksList[indexPath.row].desc
        var xString = tasksList[indexPath.row].amnt]
error 'Any object' doen't not have member name desc